Why doesn't regular expression /£?.*£?/ match string '£45.56–34.90' in PHP 8.2?
I'm using PHP 8.2.11 on Mac Sonoma 14.5.
My code is:
$cost = '£45.56–34.90';
$matches = array();
$found = preg_match(
  '/£?.*£?/',
  $cost,
  $matches
);

I'd expect preg_match() to return 1, indicating a match, and to populate $matches like this:
array (
  0 => '£45.56–34.90',
)

However, $found === 0 and $matches is empty.
I tested this on https://regex101.com, which matched as I expected.
If I change my code so that $cost === '£45.56–£34.90' (with a second pound sign added), then $found === 1 and $matches is populated as:
array (
  0 => '£45.56–£34.90',
)

If I change my code so that $cost === '£45.56–34.90' and the pattern is '/£?.*£?/g', then $found === false.

Just use /£?.*/s or /^£?.*$/s. /£?.*£?/g is not what you really want. Or ^£?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)\s*[–-]\s*£?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)$.

Use the unicode modifier: append u after the final delimiter.

The £ is not being read as that symbol because there is no u modifier indicating it is UTF8. This regex is very loose additionally. This would match anything as everything in it is optional (Unless the u modified is not present).

Unicode issues aside, your regex will match both anything and nothing; it's useless in its current state.

Thanks for the help, all. The regex I presented is a minimum working example.

@trincot Perfect – thank you. I didn't realise I needed a unicode flag.
